# Recreate a staggered layout using CSS grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to recreate the following screenshot using CSS grid, is this possible, if so what do I need to change from my code below.

**What I want to achieve:**

[image]

**My CSS so far:**

```
.alt-Cards {
 padding-top: 60px;
 padding-bottom: 60px;
 position: relative;

 &::before {
   content: '';
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 420px;
   right: 0;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   background: #e4e4e4;
  }
}

.alt-Cards_Inner {
 max-width:1440px;
 width: 100%;
 margin:0 auto;
}

.alt-Cards_Grid {
 display: grid;
 position: relative;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
 grid-column-gap: 60px;
 grid-row-gap: 60px;
}

.alt-Cards_GridItem-Titles {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}
```

**JSFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/2wztvqox/

Comment: What you have there **is not a grid**....a grid has rows of equal height...yours does not.

Comment: @Paulie_D So what are you saying?

Comment: Seems obvious to me....you can't use grid because it **isn't one**. You'll have to rethink.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container {
  width:960px;
  margin:0 auto;
  box-shadow:0 0 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%, #fff 20%, #e0e0e0 20%, #e0e0e0 100%);
  padding:50px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 405px 405px;
  grid-gap:50px;
}

.left, .right {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-start;
  align-items:center;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.left {
  margin-top:100px;
}

.left img, .right img {
  width:100%;
  margin:20px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="text">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi expedita reiciendis, eaque similique totam repellat hic quas. Aspernatur illo veniam accusantium sequi veritatis cum fuga voluptatum animi, hic reiciendis consequuntur!
    </div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="">
    <div class="text">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi expedita reiciendis, eaque similique totam repellat hic quas. Aspernatur illo veniam accusantium sequi veritatis cum fuga voluptatum animi, hic reiciendis consequuntur!
    </div>
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="">
    <div class="text">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi expedita reiciendis, eaque similique totam repellat hic quas. Aspernatur illo veniam accusantium sequi veritatis cum fuga voluptatum animi, hic reiciendis consequuntur!
    </div>
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="">
    <div class="text">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi expedita reiciendis, eaque similique totam repellat hic quas. Aspernatur illo veniam accusantium sequi veritatis cum fuga voluptatum animi, hic reiciendis consequuntur!
    </div>
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="">
    <div class="text">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi expedita reiciendis, eaque similique totam repellat hic quas. Aspernatur illo veniam accusantium sequi veritatis cum fuga voluptatum animi, hic reiciendis consequuntur!
    </div>
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="">
    <div class="text">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi expedita reiciendis, eaque similique totam repellat hic quas. Aspernatur illo veniam accusantium sequi veritatis cum fuga voluptatum animi, hic reiciendis consequuntur!
    </div>
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="">
    <div class="text">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi expedita reiciendis, eaque similique totam repellat hic quas. Aspernatur illo veniam accusantium sequi veritatis cum fuga voluptatum animi, hic reiciendis consequuntur!
    </div>
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="right">
        <div class="text">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi expedita reiciendis, eaque similique totam repellat hic quas. Aspernatur illo veniam accusantium sequi veritatis cum fuga voluptatum animi, hic reiciendis consequuntur!
    </div>
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="">
    <div class="text">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi expedita reiciendis, eaque similique totam repellat hic quas. Aspernatur illo veniam accusantium sequi veritatis cum fuga voluptatum animi, hic reiciendis consequuntur!
    </div>
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="">
    <div class="text">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi expedita reiciendis, eaque similique totam repellat hic quas. Aspernatur illo veniam accusantium sequi veritatis cum fuga voluptatum animi, hic reiciendis consequuntur!
    </div>
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="">
    <div class="text">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi expedita reiciendis, eaque similique totam repellat hic quas. Aspernatur illo veniam accusantium sequi veritatis cum fuga voluptatum animi, hic reiciendis consequuntur!
    </div>
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="">
    <div class="text">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi expedita reiciendis, eaque similique totam repellat hic quas. Aspernatur illo veniam accusantium sequi veritatis cum fuga voluptatum animi, hic reiciendis consequuntur!
    </div>
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="">
    <div class="text">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi expedita reiciendis, eaque similique totam repellat hic quas. Aspernatur illo veniam accusantium sequi veritatis cum fuga voluptatum animi, hic reiciendis consequuntur!
    </div>
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="">
    <div class="text">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi expedita reiciendis, eaque similique totam repellat hic quas. Aspernatur illo veniam accusantium sequi veritatis cum fuga voluptatum animi, hic reiciendis consequuntur!
    </div>
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Without an explanation your posted code is of limited use to either the OP *or* future visitors. Please: explain your answer; what was the OP doing wrong, what does your code correct, how does it work?

Comment: Have to say that although this is a useful answer it won't work for my use case. I need to be able to manipulate the content for mobile without having wrapper div's to control the columns

Answer (score 0):

If you know that it's always a 2 column layout, use `nth-child(odd)` to apply a translate to the grid items in the first column.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.grid {
  padding-top: 30px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 30px;
  grid-row-gap: 30px;
}

.grid-item {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 200px;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(odd) {
  transform: translatey(60px);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
</div>
```

But as commented, it isn't necessary to use grid to achieve this layout. You could achieve this easily with some flexbox.

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
}

.text,
.img {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  padding: 0 30px;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-self: center;
}

.img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

.item:first-child {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.item:first-child .text {
  margin-top: -60px;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.alt .text {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="item alt"><div class="text"><h1>Maecenas sed tincidunt est, in ullamcorper tellus. Sed accumsan dui sem, non tempor lacus auctor interdum...</h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sed tincidunt est, in ullamcorper tellus. Sed accumsan dui sem, non tempor lacus auctor interdum. Nunc eget imperdiet sem. Nullam elit diam, vestibulum efficitur metus non, condimentum facilisis turpis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla facilisi. Curabitur luctus ornare nunc, vitae sodales nunc facilisis sed. Donec ultricies enim ipsum, vitae fringilla erat tincidunt a. In scelerisque tempus porttitor. Sed dictum velit et nunc sollicitudin, at semper nulla varius. In id neque molestie mi eleifend porttitor. Nam ac ante tempus, eleifend quam id, semper lectus.</div><img src="https://picsum.photos/400/300" alt="" class="img"></div>

<div class="item "><div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sed tincidunt est, in ullamcorper tellus. Sed accumsan dui sem, non tempor lacus auctor interdum. Nunc eget imperdiet sem. Nullam elit diam, vestibulum efficitur metus non, condimentum facilisis turpis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla facilisi. Curabitur luctus ornare nunc, vitae sodales nunc facilisis sed. Donec ultricies enim ipsum, vitae fringilla erat tincidunt a. In scelerisque tempus porttitor. Sed dictum velit et nunc sollicitudin, at semper nulla varius. In id neque molestie mi eleifend porttitor. Nam ac ante tempus, eleifend quam id, semper lectus.</div><img src="https://picsum.photos/400/300" alt="" class="img"></div>

<div class="item alt"><div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sed tincidunt est, in ullamcorper tellus. Sed accumsan dui sem, non tempor lacus auctor interdum. Nunc eget imperdiet sem. Nullam elit diam, vestibulum efficitur metus non, condimentum facilisis turpis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla facilisi. Curabitur luctus ornare nunc, vitae sodales nunc facilisis sed. Donec ultricies enim ipsum, vitae fringilla erat tincidunt a. In scelerisque tempus porttitor. Sed dictum velit et nunc sollicitudin, at semper nulla varius. In id neque molestie mi eleifend porttitor. Nam ac ante tempus, eleifend quam id, semper lectus.</div><img src="https://picsum.photos/400/300" alt="" class="img"></div>

<div class="item "><div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sed tincidunt est, in ullamcorper tellus. Sed accumsan dui sem, non tempor lacus auctor interdum. Nunc eget imperdiet sem. Nullam elit diam, vestibulum efficitur metus non, condimentum facilisis turpis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla facilisi. Curabitur luctus ornare nunc, vitae sodales nunc facilisis sed. Donec ultricies enim ipsum, vitae fringilla erat tincidunt a. In scelerisque tempus porttitor. Sed dictum velit et nunc sollicitudin, at semper nulla varius. In id neque molestie mi eleifend porttitor. Nam ac ante tempus, eleifend quam id, semper lectus.</div><img src="https://picsum.photos/400/300" alt="" class="img"></div>
```